# Dynamically switch all tabs using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an html page with multiple tabs of same format throughout the page just as in [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) page itself, where there are `Markup` and `Javascript` tabs in each section.

For the purpose of my question, say all the tabs in my page are also called either `Markup` or `Javascript`. I want to have two radio buttons on the top of my page which will switch **all** the tabs throughout the page to either `Markup` or `Javascript` depending on which radio button is selected.

I am using [ui.bootrap.tabs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) but all the tabs are static, sort of like:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Markup">content for 1st markup tab</tab>
    <tab heading="Javascript">content for 1st javascript tab</tab>
</tabset>
.
.
.
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Markup">content for 2nd markup tab</tab>
    <tab heading="Javascript">content for 2nd javascript tab</tab>
</tabset>
```

and the radio buttons are also from the same source:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'markup'">markup</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'javascript'">javascript</button>
</div>
```

So far my efforts have failed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to put an expression in the active attribute of the tab that 's why it is not possible yet to do something like :

```
<tab heading="Markup" active="radioModel === 'markup'">content for 1st markup tab</tab>
```

see https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/611.

But fear not it is still possible to achieve what you want but in a more complicated/dynamic way. What I propose to you is to create a data model in your scope to hold you tabs configuration and watch the radioModel value to set/unset the active state on each tab. Something like that :

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var TabsDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {

    $scope.radioModel = 'markup';
    $scope.tabs = [
        // First tab set
        [{
            title: "Markup",
            content: "content for 1st markup tab",
            type: 'markup'
        }, {
            title: "Javascript",
            content: "content for 1st javascript tab",
            type: 'javascript'
        }],
        //Second tab set
        [{
            title: "Markup ",
            content: "content for 2nd markup tab ",
            type: 'markup'
        }, {
            title: "Javascript ",
            content: "content for 2nd javascript tab",
            type: 'javascript'
        }]
    ];


    $scope.$watch('radioModel', function (newValue) {
        //Iterate over all the tabset configuration
        angular.forEach($scope.tabs, function (value, key) {
            //iterate over each tab in a tabset
            angular.forEach(value, function (tab, key) {
                //Set the active attribute when needed 
                if (tab.type === newValue) {
                    tab.active = true;
                } else {
                    tab.active = false;
                }
            });
        });
    })
};
```

And the associated template :

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs[0]" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">{{tab.content}}</tab>
</tabset>
<br/>
<br/>
<tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs[1]" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active">{{tab.content}}</tab>
</tabset>
```

A working fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e7Tsj/3/) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a functional expression in "active" like this.

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="Markup" active="markupSelected">content for 1st markup tab</tab>
    <tab heading="Javascript" active="jsSelected">content for 1st javascript tab</tab>
```

And then simply write the function in the scope like this

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.radioModel = 'markup';
    $scope.$watch('radioModel', function(newTab) {
      $scope.markupSelected = (newTab === 'markup');
      $scope.jsSelected = (newTab === 'javascript');
    });
  });
```

Here is a working plunkr link
Updated:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hJIG5a?p=preview

Comment: this solution is very cool, but it breaks when i manually click on tabs to change them

Comment: Hi, I have update the plunker in the post with a better solution. Please let me know if this works for you. if you need to toggle buttons when user clicks on tab, let me know and I will make the change.

Comment: thanks,is it possible to change it so that changing the selected tab in one tabset will not change all the tabsets? technically if changing one tabset changes all tabsets then the radio buttons on top are not needed, but that was not what i intended,